# Spring hibernate transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

The documentation says we have to begin the transaction before doing some insertion. But how does the code below run? Because I am calling beginTransaction() after save.

```
    @Override
public void insertCustomer(Employees employee) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.save(employee);
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

And I have one more doubt on Spring's @transactional attribute called propagation which can be configured like below,

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER)
```

And this one is said to be run non-transitionally. what does that mean?

Please help me to understand the above concepts

Comment: I have no clue on what you want with the first part of your question. The second part (regarding `@Transactional`) this will only run without a transaction, as soon as it detects that it is part of a transaction it throws an exception (as explained in the reference guide).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How the below code runs? Because I am calling the begintransaction
>   after save.

Hibernate will not try to insert/update the database as soon as you call `save()`. It will try to insert only when you try to commit a transaction. If you don't commit a transaction, it will not run as you expect.

> @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER) what does that mean?

Following are the 7 different Transaction *propagation* behaviors supported by Spring

- PROPAGATION_REQUIRED (default)
- PROPAGATION_REQUIRED_NEW
- PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS
- PROPAGATION_NOT_SUPPORTED
- PROPAGATION_MANDATORY
- PROPAGATION_NEVER
- PROPAGATION_NESTED

(Note: You don't need to use a transaction in all your methods. You can also have a normal method without a transaction)

To execute a method under a transaction, annotate it with `@Transactional`. By default it runs under PROPAGATION_REQUIRED behavior which means one of the two things

1. New transaction will be activated if there is no existing transaction in the caller.
2. Join the existing transaction if one is already activated by the caller.

When a method is annotated with `@Transaction(prorogation=Propagation.NEVER)` it **shouldn't** be called, by another method, with an active transaction. Otherwise, an exception will be thrown.

`Propagation.NEVER` is used when you want a specific logic/method to be executed **strictly** without an active transaction. In my experience, I have never used this attribute. 95% of the time you will be satisfied with the default `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` behavior. However, it is good to have a knowledge on different behaviors.

Let me explain with an example:

```
@Component
public class TransactionTutorial {

    @Transactional
    public void aboutRequired() {
        //This method will create a new transaction if it is called with no active transaction 

        //Some logic that should be executed within a transaction

        //normal() method will also run under the newly created transaction.
        normal();

        //An exception will be thrown at this point
        //because aboutNever() is marked as Propagation.NEVER 
        aboutNever();
    }

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER)
    public void aboutNever() {
        //This method should be called without any active transaction.
        //If it is called under active transaction, exception will occur.

        //Some logic that should be executed without a transaction.
    }

    public void normal() {
        //This method is not bothered about surrounding transaction.
        //You can call this method with or without an active transaction.

        //Some logic
    }
}
```

Reading the above code might give better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Still I am not clear with the second answer. It runs without transaction means who will begin the transaction and commit the transaction? currently the transaction manager does that. But without transaction how it executes?

Comment: I have added more details. Please check if that helps

Comment: There is an AOP layer, that your bean invocation goes through (you have configured it in your xml or java, based on configuration you are using), that starts and ends transaction, based on meta information you specify for the method/class.

Comment: I think i was not clear in my question. I know the AOP concepts. When we put the @transactional it does some of the following activites like, begin transaction, commit, rollback etc. That happens only when you run in the transaction.

So now my doubt is annotating a method with @transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER), should not run in transaction.
So now how the transaction behavior is applied here (Begin transaction, commit, rollbacks etc).. Because now it may not call the AOP features because it is not in transaction.

Hope I am clear in my question now.

Comment: `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER)` is used when you want a method to be strictly executed without a transaction. Therefore, no transaction activities (beging, commit, rollback) is required because the method will be executed under no active transaction.

Comment: @SivaranjaniD Please ask if I'm still not clear. I'll try to explain in different terms.

Comment: This clears my question and raises one more doubt. The begin transaction is not required always?? Is it required only for insert /update?

Comment: Ask as much as you like :). Yes. You don't need a transaction (begin) for read operation. It is required only for write operation.